# what to understand with char driver examples

Tags: c, linux, driver

I have a confusion regarding char driver examples. In some examples the examples are focused in creating a character device and connecting it with file_operations. Then we have to `insmod` the driver, create a node using `mknod`, and only then our small application can read or write using this driver. A trivial init_function like this:

```
static int char_init(void)
{
    alloc_chrdev_region(&mydev, 0, 1, "mydev");
    cdev = cdev_alloc();
    cdev->fops = &fops;
    cdev_add(cdev, mydev, 1);
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Major minor number available\n");
    printk(KERN_ALERT "major number = %d minor number = %d\n",MAJOR(mydev), MINOR(mydev));//Macros that extract the major and minor numbers from a device number.
    return 0;
}
```

In some other examples we create a class and a device. An example from Derek Molloy's char driver,

```
static int __init ebbchar_init(void){
   printk(KERN_INFO "EBBChar: Initializing the EBBChar LKM\n");

   // Try to dynamically allocate a major number for the device -- more difficult but worth it
   majorNumber = register_chrdev(0, DEVICE_NAME, &fops);
   if (majorNumber<0){
      printk(KERN_ALERT "EBBChar failed to register a major number\n");
      return majorNumber;
   }
   printk(KERN_INFO "EBBChar: registered correctly with major number %d\n", majorNumber);

   // Register the device class
   ebbcharClass = class_create(THIS_MODULE, CLASS_NAME);
   if (IS_ERR(ebbcharClass)){                // Check for error and clean up if there is
      unregister_chrdev(majorNumber, DEVICE_NAME);
      printk(KERN_ALERT "Failed to register device class\n");
      return PTR_ERR(ebbcharClass);          // Correct way to return an error on a pointer
   }
   printk(KERN_INFO "EBBChar: device class registered correctly\n");

   // Register the device driver
   ebbcharDevice = device_create(ebbcharClass, NULL, MKDEV(majorNumber, 0), NULL, DEVICE_NAME);
   if (IS_ERR(ebbcharDevice)){               // Clean up if there is an error
      class_destroy(ebbcharClass);           // Repeated code but the alternative is goto statements
      unregister_chrdev(majorNumber, DEVICE_NAME);
      printk(KERN_ALERT "Failed to create the device\n");
      return PTR_ERR(ebbcharDevice);
   }
   printk(KERN_INFO "EBBChar: device class created correctly\n"); // Made it! device was initialized
   return 0;
}
```

Now what conclusions I can make with these two strategies? Why not only use the second one?
Also when we make a device using `cdev_add`, and `cdev_init`, what does it do, if I have to create a device file using `mknod`?

Comment: you can use `device_create` to create  device node, no need for `mknod`.

Comment: The mknod is a beauty of unix, where everything is a file, and the user can interact with devices via files, naming them, and giving permissions to them, as he pleases.